# Suppressing: "#warning is language extension"

Tags: xcode, clang, c-preprocessor, warnings

In an [xcode4.5](/questions/tagged/xcode4.5) project I have turned on `pedantic` warnings. But this now gives me a warning about using `#warning`:

> Lexical preprocessor issue
>       #warning is language extension

Firstly, I'd like to know why this is happening and how to stop it (with out removing the #warning).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason it's being generated is because `#warning` is an extension to the ISO standard and that is what `-pedantic` is about.

It looks like only a `#pragma` will turn it off as no `-Wno-xxx` flags appear available for language extensions.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-pedantic"

#warning blah blah blah

#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Answer (score 9):

trojanfoe answered why the issue was emitted (+1).

A more portable and language-compliant way to emit your warning message is:

```
#pragma message("YOUR WARNING HERE")
```

Clang will emit one warning (specifically, the one you wrote in the message -- not the pedantic one), and it appears in Xcode's issues.